# Swift: Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to specified type 'NSString'

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uisearchbar

General: I have a collections view app with several items from several plist depending which one the user picked. The plist is an array containing several arrays with multiple strings inside each array.

Problem: When inplementing a search bar to search through my collections (or plist), I get this error when following a tutorial.

I know this search bar code is meant to look for a string and not the string inside an array inside another array in the plist. So I'm looking for help to fix my error and the code.

Error:

> Cannot convert value of type '[Any]' to specified type 'NSString'

This is the code what is causing the error.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    filtered = car.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let tmp: NSString = text // <-- ** Error is here **
        let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })

    if(filtered.count == 0){
        searchActive = false;
    } else {
        searchActive = true;
    }

    self.finalCollectView.reloadData()
}
```

Rest of my code for SearchBar

```
func createSearchBar() {

    let mySearchBar = UISearchBar()
    mySearchBar.showsCancelButton = false
    mySearchBar.placeholder = "Search"
    mySearchBar.delegate = self
    mySearchBar.alpha = 1
    mySearchBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
    mySearchBar.searchFieldBackgroundPositionAdjustment = UIOffset(horizontal: 5, vertical: 0)

    self.navigationItem.titleView = mySearchBar
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = true;
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchActive = false;
}
```

Code for plist

```
var filtered = [[Any]]()
var searchActive: Bool = false
var car = [[Any]]()
@IBOutlet weak var finalCollectView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.finalCollectView.delegate = self
    self.finalCollectView.dataSource = self

    readList(titlePlist: "car")
}

func readList(titlePlist: String) {

    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: titlePlist, withExtension: "plist")!
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf:url)
        let sections = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [[Any]]

        car = sections

    } catch {
        print("This error must never occur: Reading plist", error)
    }
```

How the plist looks like

```
<plist> 
    <array>
        <array>
            <string>Name1</string>
            <string>Description</string>
        </array>
        <array>
            <string>Name2</string>
            <string>Description</string>
        </array>
        <array>
            <string>Name3</string>
            <string>Description</string>
        </array>
    </array>
</plist>
```

Search bar needs to search through the first string in each array. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)`, modify filtering to:

```
filtered = car.filter({ (anArray) -> Bool in
    guard let firstString = (anArray.first as? String) else{
       return false
    }
    let tmp: NSString = firstString as NSString
    let range = tmp.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)
    return range.location != NSNotFound
})
```

Comment: so this code will filter the first string in the array? When I type in the search bar it will show items depending on the name?

Comment: I tried the code and it's not working, no matter what I type to search, only the first item in the plist shows. Also if I type 'zzzzz' since nothing in the items have z the search shows all items and doesn't filter. Certain letters will show more items, but no matter what it shows the first items.

Comment: Post your code to display the search results. And does the plist have the same data that you posted? And what search text are you using to search?

Comment: What do you mean post the code? I used your exact code. The plist is an array inside that their are hundreds of arrays containing each 22 strings. First string being the name of the item. What do you mean what search text am I using?

Comment: Fixed it, my fault didn't add `if searchActive { filtered` array to `didSelectItemAt`. Also last thing if you can help me out, in `cellForItemAt` I'm setting up the images for the items using the indexPath.row but when taken to filtered the indexPath gets reseted. Since my items are in order and I'm using indexPath to assign the images it displays the wrong image. How can I get the indexPath.row of the items and save it so even when the items get copied to another array the indexPath stays put?

Comment: I was asking your tableview's datasource methods. And search text meaning what you were typing in your search bar and to match against which string. Anyways glad you found it working. For your images, a good way is to associate the images with your datasource. That way even when you filter you can get the associated image. If not you'll have to get the old indices of the current displayed data and then use them to get corresponding images.

Comment: You can get old indices of the data by maintaining two diff arrays (original data array and filtered data array) and then use index(where:) to get indices of elements in original array for each of the elements in the filtered array.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to search through the first elements of the inner arrays of `car`, you should use `flatMap` to get the first elements. You should also cast the elements to `NSString` right away to avoid having to cast inside the `filter`.

```
filtered = car.flatMap({$0.first as? NSString})filter({ (text) -> Bool in...
```

However, your choice for a data structure is rather weird. Why would you declare `car` as `[[Any]]`, when it only contains `String`s and when the inner arrays clearly look like they should be a dictionary rather than an array? I would suggest you declare `car` as `[[String:String]]` and modify your `.plist` file accordingly.